# No carga CSS en servidor NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, express

Tengo el siguiente servidor básico:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  });
  
app.listen(8081);
```

En ese index.html tengo referenciado a unos CSS que se encuentran en la misma carpeta public. La ruta es correcta, ya que si abro el html con el explorador me sale de la forma correcta, pero si entro a través del servidor (es decir en localhost:8081) me sale el html plano, sin el CSS.
Qué tengo que añadir en mi servidor NodeJS?

Los CSS los referencio desde el `index.html` de esta forma:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
```

Comment: Seria bueno que editaras la pregunta y adiciones el código de tú pagina `index.html`. Puede que el problema este dentro de ese HTML.

Comment: No creo que el problema sea del HTML, ya que si lo abro con el explorador me sale de forma correcta, me sale HTML plano sólo mediante el servidor. No lo añadí a la pregunta ya que es bastante extenso.

Comment: Entonces adiciona solo el encabezado del HTML donde estas haciendo las referencias a las hojas de estilo. Adicionalmente te indico que para el tema de hospedaje de sitios Web, no es lo mismo referenciar los directorios del Sistema operativo que los directorios virtuales dentro del Sitio Web

Comment: Puede ser ese el problema, ahí he añadido la línea donde referencio los directorios. Lo hago de forma normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta el siguiente código, básicamente te estaría haciendo falta indicarle a la app donde estan ubicados los archivos estáticos (css, js, imágenes, etc.)

```
// Se cargan los modulos necesarios.
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

// Crea una Express app.
var app = express();

// obtiene la ruta del directorio publico donde se encuentran los elementos estaticos (css, js).
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'); //path.join(__dirname, 'public'); también puede ser una opción

// Para que los archivos estaticos queden disponibles.
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  });

app.listen(8081);
```

Comment: @IbrahimHernandezJorge, si la respuesta te sirvió seria bueno que la marcaras como correcta, para que otras personas puedan acceder a ella mas fácilmente.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y efectivamente funciona, muchas gracias.